# how get current position with Here map js 3 api?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, here-api

how can  getCurrentPosition with here map 3 api?

var positioning = new nokia.maps.positioning.Manager(); // this code v2
 positioning.getCurrentPosition();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily replace it with the standard Geolocation API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation). You will find that the signatures match pretty much.

Just make sure you check whether there actually is a geolocation object in navigator.

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  console.log(position);
});
```

Comment: thanks this code user  browser(html5) api but i want to use here map api

Comment: If you take a look at the compressed code of the positioning module in the v2 API (http://js.api.here.com/se/2.5.4/positioning-w3c.js) you will see that the module only wraps the browsers geolocation API:

`k=navigator.geolocation;`
`getCurrentPosition:function(c,d,b){k.getCurrentPosition(c,d,b)}`

V3 doesn't have positioning functionality at all... And why would it if there's a standardized API to this built-in in the browser?